# Biztalk Server backup Job on SQL Server 2000 fails

Tags: sql-server, biztalk, msdasql

We have a Biztalk Server working with SQL Server 2000 at backend. The Biztalk created Backup Job for Full backups and Tran Log backups suddenly started failing with error as below. It uses service Account. Any help with MSDASQL will be appretiated.

> OLE DB provider 'MSDASQL' reported an error. Authentication failed.
>
> **[SQLSTATE 42000] (Error 7399)**
>
> Login failed for user '(null)'. Reason: Not associated with a trusted SQL Server connection.
>
> **[SQLSTATE 01000] (Error 7312)**
>
> OLE DB error trace [OLE/DB Provider 'MSDASQL' IDBInitialize::Initialize returned 0x80040e4d:  Authentication failed.].
>
> **[SQLSTATE 01000] (Error 7300)**
>
> The step failed.

Comment: Is the message box or any other BTS database on a separate SQL server?

Comment: yes the BTS is seperate.

Answer (score 0):

Authentication problem are never fun...

1. First check which account the two failing jobb are running as. (SQL
   Server Manager studio => SQL Server Agent => properties on the job
   Backup BizTalk Server (BizTalkMgmtDb))
2. Verify that the credentials that the service account is using are correct.
3. If the service account is a domain account, verify that the SQL can
   access the domain controller.
4. Verify that MSDTC are running (the job uses DTC transactions to
   execute, and errors from MSDTC usually don’t say DTC problem, it
   sometimes says Authentication error)
5. Check history on the failing job, and see if you can get some more information about the authentication error.
6. Check history on the failing job and see when it last run successfully. Then check the event log at this time, and see if there are any clues to what has changed.

Comment: Linus, thanks for the reply. But I checked all the above settings you mentioned and everything looks fine. But I still keep getting the same error.